# must convert dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in input type date

Tags: angularjs, date

**selectdata.php***
code to select data from php

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $response = array();
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chatapp");
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $Email = $json['Email'];
    $Sql = "SELECT Name, Email, DOB, Password, ConfirmPassword, registered_time FROM user_register WHERE Email = '$Email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $Sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $response[] = $row;
        }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**profiletemplate.html**
this is the code where it displays the output.

```html
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
            <h3>Your Details</h3>
            <div class="table-reponsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <div class="form-field-group">
                        <form name="update" ng-submit="Update()" novalidate>
                            <p>{{ success }}</p>
                            <p>{{ error }}</p>
                            <tbody ng-repeat="results in namess">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th> 
                                    <td><input type="text" value="{{ results.Name }}" class="form-field" ng-model="results.Name"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <td><input type="email" value="{{ results.Email }}" class="form-field" ng-model="results.Email"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>DOB</th>
                                    <td><input type="date" value="{{ results.DOB }}" class="form-field" ng-model="results.DOB"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Password</th>
                                    <td><input type="password" value="{{ results.Password }}" class="form-field" ng-model="results.Password"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Registered Time</th>
                                    <td>{{ results.registered_time }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="update" class="darkblue-button" value="Update"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**controller.js**
this is the code where the data is selected from and updated

```
chat.controller("profileController", function($scope, $http){
    //displayes the username in page
    $scope.displayName = localStorage.getItem("Name");
    var $Email = localStorage.getItem("Email");
    //console.log($Email);
    //selects the data according to user
    $http.post("selectdata.php",{
        'Email': $Email
    })
    //displays the selected data
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.namess = response.data;
    });
    //updates the data according to user
    $scope.Update = function(){
        $http.post("update.php", {
            'Name': $scope.Name,
            'Email': $scope.Email,
            'DOB': $scope.DOB,
            'Password': $scope.Password
        })
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.success = "updated successfully";
        }, function(){
            $scope.error = "not updated";
        });
    }
});
```

**error**

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2000-11-07
    at angular.js:99
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:26870)
    at Object.$$format (angular.js:31244)
    at Object.$processModelValue (angular.js:31224)
    at Object.$$setModelValue (angular.js:31256)
    at angular.js:31295
    at m.$digest (angular.js:19262)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:19630)
    at k (angular.js:13473)
    at v (angular.js:13730)
```

**warning**
The specified value "{{ results.DOB }}" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
input type="date" format should be yyyy-mm-dd how to change it.

Comment: So, where does `results.DOB` come from exactly? From an API or something? Or elsewhere? It would make sense to pre-format it before passing it to your angular model

Comment: it comes from database

Comment: Well 1) what is the database doing outputting in an ambiguous format to begin with? And 2) I really hope that it's not _storing_ it as text in that format? You should be using your database's date or DateTime column type and then always outputting in yyyy-mm-dd format to avoid any chance of the date being misinterpreted (dd-mm-yyyy can look a lot like mm-dd-yyyy sometimes). So the solution to your issue is really in your backend, not in angular or html

Comment: @ADyson in the database date is stored as yyyy-mm-dd and while getting data the format is yyyy-mm-dd but while adding it to form field it displays as dd-mm-yyyy. and warning says `results.DOB` does not conform the required format yyyy-mm-dd so what is the solution for this ??

Comment: `while getting data the format is yyyy-mm-dd but while adding it to form field it displays as dd-mm-yyyy.` maybe something goes wrong in between those two steps and it gets re-formatted. We can't see your code so we don't know what all the steps are and we can't suggest any fix without knowing. have you attempted to trace it yourself and debug it?

Comment: @ADyson  i tried to fix the code but could not fix it. the code is given above

Comment: Ok. So have you debugged it? I can't see your data, remember. What format is the date in when it's returned from PHP? You can check the raw return data by looking on your browser's network tool and looking at the raw response from the call to the PHP script. That's your first step. If the format is correct there, then trace it further - from your code it's unclear how the data gets from `$scope.namess` into the profile template (I'm not an angular expert but I can't see how they're wired up, from what you've shown).